# How to save multiple lists in a single CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, format, row

I have the following python code that generates two lists as output. The first list is an author list, I want it to come in the second column (equivalent B column in Excel), a second list is a title list, I want it to come in the third column (C column).

The current output in the console is like this:

```
***FAILED TO DOWNLOAD*** http://grupodyasa.com/14-gauge-qvb0w/pipsc-collective-agreement-2019.html,
28  contents successfully fetched, 
1 failed to fetch
```

At present there are 3 mistakes:

1. they all come in one column (the A column in excel)
2. Titles written in the same column as consequent letters, each letter occupies one row/line.
3. I want statistics of exceptions should be reflected in the file (at the end of every row): 1. when the code did not fetch the author name, 2. when the code did not fetch a title), 3. above all when the code did not download the anything from a URL.

My code is below:

```
from newspaper import Config
from newspaper import Article
from newspaper import ArticleException
import csv

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'

config = Config()
config.browser_user_agent = USER_AGENT
config.request_timeout = 10

file1 = open('laborAuthorTitle4.csv', 'w') 
w = csv.writer(file1)
count1=0
failCount=0
titleFail=0
authorFail=0
article_authors=[]

row1=[]

with open('laborURL29.csv', 'r') as file:
    csv_file = file.readlines()
    for url in csv_file:
        try:
            article = Article(url.strip(), config=config)
            article.download()
            article.parse()
            article_authors=article.authors
            for persons in article_authors:
                try:
                    my_row = []
                    my_row.append(persons)
                    w.writerow(my_row)
                except ArticleException:
                    print('***FAILED TO FETCH AUTHOR***', article.url)
                    authorFail=authorFail+1
                    print('Total fails', authorFail)
            article_titles=article.title
            for thema in article_titles:
                try:
                    my_row2 = []
                    my_row2.append(thema)
                    w.writerow(my_row2)
                except ArticleException:
                    print('***FAILED TO EXTRACT A TITLE***', article.url)
                    titleFail=titleFail+1
                    print('Total fails', titleFail)
            count1=count1+1
        except ArticleException:
            print('***FAILED TO DOWNLOAD***', article.url)
            failCount=failCount+1
file1.close()
print(count1, " contents successfully fetched")
print(failCount, "failed to fetch ")
```

The created/written csv file is here [laborAuthors11](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u4kv72lpw03o2ja/laborAuthors11.csv?dl=0)

Here's a screenshot of the beginning of it:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I can't run your code, but from the resulting CSV file it looks like you're passing `writerow()` a string as an argument, not a `list`—so it interprets each _character_ of the string as a separate row.

Comment: Did you look at the **Saving Extracted Data** section of my overview document that I previously shared with you? I cover saving to CSV, JSON, HTML and dataframes.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex, no, well I did not notice existance of it. I will check.

Answer (score 0):

Just from reading this code:

```
        for persons in article_authors:
            my_row = []
            my_row.append(persons)
            w.writerow(my_row)
        article_titles=article.title
        for thema in article_titles:
            my_row2 = []
            my_row2.append(thema)
            w.writerow(my_row2)
```

I see two potential issues:

1. You're writing the row *before* all values are appended
2. You're iterating over the `article.title`, most likely a string, and appending characters one by one (hence why each row contains a single character, not the full title)

Here's what I think your code should look like:

```
            row = []
            row.append(article_authors[0])  # take the first author
            row.append(article.title)
            w.writerow(row)
```

That might be 100% correct but it should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I got Article authors this way: for persons in article_authors:if persons:  my_row = [] my_row.append(persons)    w.writerow(my_row)    else:            w.writerow('Failed')   article_titles=article.title   my_row.append(article_titles)    #### but author and titles are now in the same column, how to put titles in second column?